# Can I send messages between objects without photonView in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am making a 3D online mobile game in unity C#. I want the room to wait until everyone in the room to load the scene. I made a waiting UI for people who joined early but I can't find a clear way to cout the players who have things such as entered the scene without writing dirty code such as making a syncronized counter object. 
 **Can I send messages between objects without photonView in Unity C#?**

Comment: Or a way to count players who have loaded the scene in a clean method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't find a clear way to cout the players who have things such as
>   entered the scene without writing dirty code such as making a
>   syncronized counter object

From Master Client (`PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient` check), check the number of actors joined to the room whenever a new player joins (inside `IInRoomCallbacks.OnPlayerEnteredRoom` callback, read about callbacks [here](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/v2/getting-started/dotnet-callbacks)). If the number matches the one you expect, load the level from the Master Client using the Photon method (`PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel`, see reference API [here](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_photon_network.html#aedba3c40295e3684fedc64acf678a5cd)) and not the default Unity method. All clients of other joined players will follow automatically.

> Can I send messages between objects without photonView in Unity C#?

Yes. Use custom events via `PhotonNetwork.RaiseEvent`. Read more about it [here](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/rpcsandraiseevent#raiseevent).